# Derived public class doesn't inherit protected variable

Tags: c++

So I have three classes which are the following:

The Person class:

```
#ifndef INC_7__LABOR_PERSON_H
#define INC_7__LABOR_PERSON_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Person{
protected:
    string lastName;
    string firstName;
    int dateOfBirth;
public:
    Person(const string &lastName, const string &firstName, int dateOfBirth);
    virtual void print(ostream& os = cout) const; //a virtualtol polimorfikus lehet.
};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Person&);

#endif //INC_7__LABOR_PERSON_H
```

The constructor for Person:

```
Person::Person(const string &lastName, const string &firstName, int dateOfBirth) : lastName(lastName),
                                                                                   firstName(firstName),
                                                                                   dateOfBirth(dateOfBirth) {}
```

The Employee class:

```
#ifndef INC_7__LABOR_EMPLOYEE_H
#define INC_7__LABOR_EMPLOYEE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Person.h"
using namespace std;


class Employee : public Person{
protected:
    string position;
    static int counter;
    int id;
public:
    Employee(const string &lastName, const string &firstName, int dateOfBirth, const string &position);

    Employee(const string &lastName, const string &firstName, int dateOfBirth, int id);

    virtual void print(ostream& os = cout) const;

    int getId() const;
};


#endif //INC_7__LABOR_EMPLOYEE_H
```

The constructor for Employee:

```
Employee::Employee(const string &lastName, const string &firstName, int dateOfBirth, const string &position)
        : Person(lastName, firstName, dateOfBirth), position(position), id(counter++){}
```

The Manager class:

```
#ifndef INC_7__LABOR_MANAGER_H
#define INC_7__LABOR_MANAGER_H
#include "Employee.h"
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class Manager : public Employee{
private:
    vector<Employee*> employees;

public:

    Manager(const string &lastName, const string &firstName, int dateOfBirth, const string &position);
    static string MANAGER_POSITION;
    virtual void print(ostream& os = cout) const;
    void addEmployee(Employee*);
    void deleteEmployee(int);
};




#endif //INC_7__LABOR_MANAGER_H
```

The constructor for Manager:

```
string Manager::MANAGER_POSITION="manager";

Manager::Manager(const string &lastName, const string &firstName, int dateOfBirth, const string &position)
        : Employee(lastName, firstName, dateOfBirth, position) {}
```

Now my problem is that I cannot reach the id variable through the manager:

```
void Manager::deleteEmployee(int id)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < employees.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(employees.at(i)->id == id) //HERE the "employees.at(i)->id" is the problem.
        {
            employees.erase(employees.begin() + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Although the id variable is protected the program cannot access it.
I solved the problem by using a getter getId(), but I would like to know why I cannot access it without getter.

The program was written in c++14 with cygwin compiler.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`INC_7__LABOR_PERSON_H`, `INC_7__LABOR_EMPLOYEE_H`, `INC_7__LABOR_MANAGER_H`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: These are made automatically by Clion.

Comment: Doesn't matter where they came from. They're reserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is that this is because that's how inheritance in C++ works.

Your `Manager` class is attempting to access a member of an `Employee` class that it inherits as `protected` from `Person`. It is a ***separate*** `Employee` object at hand, and it's trying to get at its protected member.

Something that's `protected` cannot be accessed from other classes. It is true that `Manager` inherits from `Employee`, but that only means that `Manager`, ***in its own class*** only, can access all of the `protected` and `public` fields that it inherits.

Your code example can be reduced to a much shorter, bare bones, single compilable example (please take some effort to do the same in your next question, after reading stackoverflow's requirements for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because it will help others understand your question better):

```
class a {
protected:
    int b;
};

class c : public a {

};

class d : public c {

public:
    int method();
};

c *p;
d *q;

int d::method()
{
    return b;    // This is ok
    return p->b; // This is an error
    return q->b; // But this is ok
}
```

Even though `d` inherits from `c`, they are still two distinct classes, and if `d` is accessing a ***distinct*** `c` object, it cannot access its protected members.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Next time I will simplify my question.